# Could we make the state label on the timeline view readable?

Tags: feature-request, design, timeline

I noticed this on the timeline view (`/posts/#/timeline`):

[image]

Ick. Thinking it was just a Stack Overflow issue, I check some timelines on site with different themes:

[image][image]

Hmm... not much variety.

Could we make it readable?

```
.td-state
{
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Which turns out a much better looking label:

[image]

Comment: You should have mentioned that it is applicable for deleted or closed questions only... :/

Comment: I probably should have :P